# Need help regarding Hot-spot Analysis through ArcGIS JSAPI 3.6/3.7

Tags: arcgis-server, arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript

I am going through [Hotspot Analysis through java script sample](https://developers.arcgis.com/en/javascript/jssamples/analysis_hotspot.html) and I want to perform similar thing at my end.

While accessing this sample it taking too much time to display the result (for sign in I created 30 day trial account so is that matter to access the sample?)

-According to this sample ESRI mention that if you want to use this type of service then you need to subscribe the ArcGIS Online analysis service (Why ? we have ArcGIS  Server which itself costly product then why should we again purchase the ArcGIS Online?)

-Can I create similar service at my end using geo-processing and use in the code?

-In future if I want to use spatial analysis services then ArcGIS Online subscription will be necessary ? (If so then whats the importance of having ArcGIS Enterprise Advance license?)

Any help regarding this will be great !

Software suit: ESRI 10.1 and ArcGIS JSPAI version 3.6/3.7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, if you want to use these services as they are in the samples, you will need to have an ArcGIS for Organizations account. You're in luck if you have any desktop licenses where the maintenance is up to date.

From an email I received in August from ESRI. This has already been implemented on our organizational account (and we are still on 10.1).

[image]

So you should have access to ArcGIS Online via that avenue. Contact your sales rep if you have any questions.

To the second question, yes you can create your own geoprocessing services and reference them via your app. Check out the [server help files](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#/An_overview_of_geoprocessing_REST_Services/005700000065000000/) for information on how to get started with that.